# What's an engine good for 3D RPG development?

Tags: game-development, optimization

**The task I want to accomplish:** Create a 3D RPG by using an optimized 3D engine.

 
**The requirements for the task:** An engine that requires a good amount of coding knowledge, can handle 3D graphics with ease and is exportable to multiple platforms.
**What I know:** Several tools like RPG Maker can't use 3D graphics, and are limited to scripts hard-coded into the system (unless I make several plugins, which would take longer than using a 3D engine).

**What do I want to know:** Is there an engine that I can use to make a 3D RPG that fits these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity3d and the Unreal engine are 2 game engines that will do what you want. They both support 3d graphics.

I have used Unity3d, it's designed to make it easiest to script in c#. It lets you add 3d assets and has a free tier. It has a great community of developers from individuals to larger groups they don't ask you for any future income if your game is a huge hit, just that you pay the monthly subscription if your income or assets are higher than a cutoff.

I have looked into the Unreal engine a little bit but haven't used it beyond opening it and running the example. It also supports 3d assets. I think that they suggest using c++ to do scripting. They also have a free tier but request a percentage of income if you make more than a particular cutoff.

Both of these allow exporting to multiple platforms.

Best of luck with your game!